GSAP ScrollTo wrong position
I've created a scrolling container inside of the section. And it works just fine until I got to the next-prev buttons. The issue here is that scrollTo miscalculates the scroll position and sections become stuck in between. I've tried everything passing ids, scroll values, elements, even add fixed value on scroll (e.g. 200px). But no help.
Here is my codepen. You can scroll down to section #3, and then play with buttons.
<section class="mp-block">SCROLL DOWN</section>
<section class="mp-block">AND A BIT MORE</section>
<section class="mp-block mp-block--components">
  <div>
    <div class="scroll-container">
        <div class="scroll-item" id="item-1">1</div>
        <div class="scroll-item" id="item-2">2</div>
        <div class="scroll-item" id="item-3">3</div>
        <div class="scroll-item" id="item-4">4</div>
        <div class="scroll-item" id="item-5">5</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div>
    HERE IS A PROBLEMATIC SECTION, WHEN PRESSING THE BUTTONS THE INNER SCROLL POSITION IS WRONG <br>
    <div class="slider-buttons">
      <a href="#" class='button prev'>Prev</a>
      <a href="#" class='button next'>Next</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="mp-block"></section>
<section class="mp-block"></section>
<section class="mp-block"></section>


let sections = gsap.utils.toArray(".scroll-container .scroll-item");
let buttonNext = $('.slider-buttons .next');
let buttonPrev = $('.slider-buttons .prev');

let currentIndex = 0;

const originalConfig = {
  yPercent: -100 * (sections.length - 1), 
  ease: "none", 
  scrollTrigger: {
    markers: true,
    trigger: '.mp-block--components', 
    pin: true, 
    scrub: 1,
    pinSpacing: true,
    end: () => "+=" + sections.map(sec => sec.offsetHeight).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
      return accumulator + currentValue
    }, -50),
    onUpdate: (trigger) => {
      let newIndex = Math.round(trigger.progress * (sections.length - 1));
      if (newIndex !== currentIndex) {
        currentIndex = newIndex;
        buttonPrev.css({opacity: currentIndex == 0 ? 0.6 : 1});
        buttonNext.css({opacity: currentIndex == sections.length - 1 ? 0.6 : 1});
      }
    }
  }
};

gsap.to(sections, originalConfig)

function goToSection(index) {
  
  console.log(index);

  if (index >= 0 && index < sections.length) {
    gsap.to(window, {
      scrollTo: {
        y: '#'+sections[index].id,
        autoKill: false
      },
      duration: 1
    });
  }else {
    console.log('out of range')
  }
}
  
 buttonPrev.on('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  goToSection(currentIndex-1);
});

buttonNext.on('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  goToSection(currentIndex+1);
});```

